# test onWrite firestore function using postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement `stripe` charge functionality with `firestore` cloud function and I found this function on stackoverflow thread. I have never used functions who use stripe triggers so I am struggling to test this function with `postman`. Is there any way that I can test this function using `postman`? If yes then do tell me how but if I cannot do that then I would like to know how can I use this function with my `angular` app that contains a component named paymentRequest. Here is the function

```
exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
  .document('/users/{userId}/payments/{paymentId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const payment = event.data.data()
    const userId = event.params.userId
    const paymentId = event.params.paymentId

    // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
    if (!payment || payment.charge) return

    return admin.firestore()
      .doc(`/users/${userId}`)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot
      })
      .then(customer => {
        const amount = payment.price * 100 // amount must be in cents
        const idempotency_key = paymentId  // prevent duplicate charges
        const source = payment.token.id
        const currency = 'usd'
        const description = 'irl Map Fine Print'
        const charge = {amount, currency, source}

        return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key })
     })
     .then(charge => {
       admin.firestore()
        .doc(`/users/${userId}/payments/${paymentId}`)
        .set({
          charge: charge
        }, { merge: true })
     })
   });
```

Comment: can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Postman cannot invoke Firestore triggers directly.  It can only invoke HTTP type functions using their endpoint URL.

If you want to invoke this function, just create or modify a document that matches the document pattern, either using the Firebase console, or some other code you write.